# Accessing img from Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am developing an app that needs to generate a static image from Google Maps, process it and then reupload it.

I save it to a variable:

```
var img = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(img)
    img.innerHTML = "<img src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=35.510900927600225,24.016252229213706&zoom=19&size=400x400&maptype=satellite&key=AIzaSyDbccgp5K3qn8Sh5IFKoqZ2RGyg8G8bqZ8'></img>";
```

and I need to access this image from my `app.py` file.

Any ideas?

Comment: send image source as ajax post request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am showing a way to add alternative text for your image using AJAX.

`application.py`

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/show_map_result', methods=['GET','POST'])
def show_map_result():
    if request.method == "POST":
        image_data = request.form.get("image_data")
        # Work on the received value as required
        return "Sample image alternate message"
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('show_index'))

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def show_index():
    return render_template("google_map.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The template `google_map.html` contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="author" content="Ahmedur Rahman Shovon">
    <title>AJAX Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="load_map">Load Map</button>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            function ajax_request(){
                $img_tag = '<img id="image_map" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=35.510900927600225,24.016252229213706&zoom=19&size=400x400&maptype=satellite&key=AIzaSyDbccgp5K3qn8Sh5IFKoqZ2RGyg8G8bqZ8"/>';
                $img_div = '<div id="image_div">'+$img_tag+'</div>';
                $("#map").html($img_div);

                $.ajax({
                    url: '{{ url_for("show_map_result") }}',
                    data: {
                        "image_data" : $img_div,
                    },
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(response) {
                        $("#image_map").attr("alt", response);                      
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                    }
                });             
            }
            $("#load_map").on("click", function () {
                ajax_request();
            });
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image: accessing image alternative text]

The alternative text was passed from the Flask file to the template. And after the AJAX request is invoked the alternative text has been added to the newly created image. It demonstrates that you can access any DOM element(dynamic or static) from Flask using AJAX.